# Problems with observable property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript, knockout-2.0, computed-observable

I have a ViewModel with some filters properties:

```
class IndexModel
    TermoBusca: ko.observable()

class ViewModel extends IndexModel
    Nome: ko.observable()
    Endereco: ko.observable()
    Contato: ko.observable()
    Responsaveis: ko.observableArray []
    ResponsaveisSelected: ko.observableArray []
```

And a computed property that generates a URL OData

```
@Url = ko.computed
    read: ->
        console.count "@Url:read called!"

        urlBase = "api/empresas?$expand=Teste"
        #return "#{urlBase}&#{@TermoBusca()}" if @TermoBusca() and @TermoBusca().indexOf("$filter") == 0

        group = []

        if @Nome()
            group.push "Name eq #{@Nome()}"

        if @Endereco()
            group.push "substringof('#{@Endereco()}', Endereco)"

        if @Contato()
            contatos = @Contato().split(/[\s,.]+/)
            group.push "(" + ko.utils.arrayMap(contatos, (nome) -> "substringof('#{nome}', Contato/Nome)").join(" or ") + ")"

        responsaveisSelected = ko.utils.unwrapObservable @ResponsaveisSelected()
        if responsaveisSelected and responsaveisSelected.length > 0
            group.push "(" + ko.utils.arrayMap(responsaveisSelected, (id) -> "Responsaveis/Id eq " + id ).join(" or ") + ")"

        if group.length > 0
            urlFilter = "$filter=#{group.join(' and ')}"
            #@TermoBusca urlFilter
            return "#{urlBase}?#{urlFilter}"
        urlBase
    owner: @
    deferEvaluation: true
```

The idea is simple. As the user enters filters, the OData URL is generated automatically!

And its works: https://c9.io/ridermansb/knockoutjsobservable/workspace/index.html

**New functionality**

The idea is to put a single text field, and in it you can create your filter:

For example: *luci* will search by name and address.
It is possible to use special characters, something like: *@mike* will search for contact name

The property `TermoBusca` is a text field where the user enters their search and it is converted to an OData Url.

But I can not make it work!

The complete code is in: https://c9.io/ridermansb/knockoutjsobservable

**I'm using git!**

The branch *master*, not have the property `TermoBusca`!
The branch *termo_busca* contains the implementation of the single text field.

See this vídeo: http://screenr.com/AMj7

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? you are getting wrong url, or you are not getting data from observable?

Comment: There are two ways to enter a filter:  
1. In the **master branch** only has the option for filters field by field.
2. Was implanted in **branch termo_busca** the option of a single field search. The user tells the filter. And it is translated to OData url (`Url` property).  
**My problem is** that when deployed the single field search, this implementation breaks the url. (It is no longer generated!)  
This video shows the functionality: http://www.screenr.com/AMj7

Source: https://c9.io/ridermansb/knockoutjsobservable